# 2000 Chevy Silverado abs engaging 5mph

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, abs, silverado

My 4.3L 4x4 base pickup has the abs engage everytime Im braking at 5-6 mph replaced abs module front wheel sensors and speed sensor on tail of transfer case bleed the abs module with diagnostic tool still engaging when taking it up the road the rear speed sensor trails behind the front and when braking it dips to zero when abs engages the others don't went and cleaned the connections on the ecm nothing what do I do next

Comment: Did it get better for awhile (weeks?) after you replaced the front wheel sensors? Then resumed engaging every time you stop?

Comment: Did you change the front hub assemblies with the sensors or just the sensors?  Worn bearings can cause ABS issues.

Comment: The issue hasn't went away ever and haven't changed the hub assembly because the front sensors read the same on the scanner I would think if the hub was bad they would be wrong

Comment: Have you checked to ensure your tires are all the same size?

Comment: Tires are the same size

Answer (score 1):

The following can also cause issues like this -

- Cracked [Reluctor Ring](https://www.reluctorrings.com/)
- Rusty Reluctor Ring
- Worn wheel bearing (allows the ABS sensor to move away from the
  reluctor ring)
- Rust stopping the ABS sensor seating close to the reluctor ring

[image]

On some vehicles it is easy to see the reluctor ring, on others you may have to remove the sensor to view it.  Do they look clean and are firmly attached?  Can you see any cracks?

Check the wheel bearing for play.

Comment: Would t that make the front speed sensors read wrong, an no play in the bearing

Comment: Presumably there are ASB sensors on the rear wheels too? Have you checked those?  When you talk about the front and rear speed sensors, does it have 2 or is it getting the speed from the ABS sensors?

Comment: There is a sensor on the front and rear of the transfer case I replaced the one that reads the speed going to the rear drive shaft on the tail end of the transfer case with no change in symptoms afterwards

Comment: These sensors drop input to the abs module at 4.5 mph. You should double check with the scanner and check each sensor to see if they all match speed at 4.5 and higher. The one that doesn't match is the problem. If it's a sensor in the tranny, find which one feeds the abs module. Then check sensor reluctor connectors and wiring. It's probably going to be found in these areas.

Comment: Another thing to check is to see if the reluctor ring is fully seated and not spinning in place. Very rarely would this happen, but it is still a posibility.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correct the reluctor ring is in the wheel hubs  which my speed sensors are in the front two wheel which are reading correct the rear is reading incorrectly measuring on the tail end of the transfer case that sensor has been replaced